# sqlite Query getting name from another table by id from first

Tags: sqlite

This is a beginner question (I am not to good with databases at the moment)
But here goes I have 2 tables

Table 1 
User

```
 id - name - status_id
  0    John     0
  1    Jim      1
  2    Stan     0
```

Table 2 
Status

```
 id - name
  0    employed
  1    Not employed
```

I want to make a query that gives me Status name from User id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the two tables on `User.status_id` and `Status.id`. Then select the user you are interested in.

```
select s.name
  from User as u,
       Status as s
 where u.status_id = s.id
   and u.id = 1;
```